# Homotopic Topology by Fomenko, Fuchs, Gutenmacher

Tags: reference-request

Does anyone know where I can find the Russian version of this book? If you are not familiar with it, it can be found here:
[Homotopic Topology](https://sites.google.com/site/vaguten/homotopic-topology)

Thanks!

Comment: I can tell you about English version

Comment: The link above actually sends you to the English version itself. Thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took a bit of hunting to learn that Fuchs is given as first author in the original (1969) edition (which, incidentally, is in typescript).  I turned this up under Гомотопическая топология :

http://bookre.org/reader?file=577739

I'm finding numerous places where you can get a DejaVu file [for instance,

http://lib.freescienceengineering.org/view.php?id=141221 ],

but no .pdf file. It looks like someone made one .djvu file of the book at some point, which everyone else in turn posted at various locations.

[It was much easier to find the out-of-print English translation or a collection of Fomenko's illustrations than this...]

Comment: This is probably as good as it gets, I really appreciate the help, you are certainly more resourceful than I am!